# Non-static field initialized before a static field

Tags: java, static, initialization-order

**Note:** I was going to post it as a question, but my attempts to reproduce the problem in a SSCCE led me to the solution posted below.

I have a class in my code, where a `private`, non-`static` field, is initialized *before* a `static` `final` field. I couldn't reproduce the problem in the following SSCCE:

```
public class MyClass {

    private static final File myDefaultPath = 
                new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "DefaultPath");

    private JFileChooser myFileChooser = new JFileChooser() {

        // File chooser initialization block:
        {
            myDefaultPath.mkdirs(); 
                // In my code, the above line throws:
                // java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                // Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                //    at init.order.MyClass$1.<init>(MyClass.java:18)
                //    at init.order.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.java:14)
                //    at init.order.MyClass.<clinit>(MyClass.java:9)
            setCurrentDirectory(myDefaultPath);
        }
    };

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new MyClass().myFileChooser.showDialog(null, "Choose");
    }
}
```

For some reason the `File myDefaultPath` is not initialized before the `JFileChooser myFileChooser`.

Shouldn't `static` (especially `static final`) fields be initialized first?

Comment: -1 for knowingly asking a question which has the important information missing.

Comment: @Peter: I knowingly posted the question Q&A style, as noted above. It is meant to help others who might run into the same problem, and probably won't know in advanced what is the missing information that causes the problem (otherwise they know the solution already).

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the -1 on the question means that many users won't even read it, which makes the +1 on the answer meanningless...

Comment: If you are warning users to read all the stack trace, or all the relevant code, you could make that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

In my code, my class stores a `static` instance of itself (a singleton), which fields are initiated *before* any other `static` field that comes textually after the singleton initialization:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static MyClass c = 
            new MyClass();

    private static final File myDefaultPath = 
                new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "DefaultPath");

    private JFileChooser myFileChooser = new JFileChooser() {

        // File chooser initialization block:
        {
            myDefaultPath.mkdirs(); // This code *will* throw an exception!
            setCurrentDirectory(myDefaultPath);
        }
    };

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        c.myFileChooser.showDialog(null, "Choose");
    }
}
```

Possible solutions are:

Move `myDefaultPath` initialization before the singleton initialization.

Modify `myDefaultPath` to be a compile time constant (and keep it's `static` and `final` modifiers) to get it to initialize before all other members of `MyClass` (for example, make it a hard coded `String` path).

Comment: +1 As you point out, the code which is having a problem is not the code presented in the question.  This is a common mistake which makes answering the question hard.  As you point out, with the real code the answer is more obvious that the class is being initialised first but you have defined it in such a way that you are creating an object and in this case clearly a mistake.